# Windows batch - Why is this happening?

Tags: windows, batch-file

if 52524302617.60 lss 9660035072 (echo WRONG) else (echo Correct!)

Returns WRONG each time.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetics in the `cmd` shell are limited to integers, and `if` only performs numerical comparison if both sides consist entirely of digits.

Since `52524302617.60` has a `.` in it, a *string* comparison is performed using [`lstrcmp()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's a String compare and there is a max of character that are considered for compare.

as in the other answer by *[grawity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182046/windows-batch-why-is-this-happening/5182236#5182236)* it's only a numeric compare if both strings can be converted to integer and this assumes no decimal point and not more than 10 digits.

Comment: Re "no decimal point and not more than 10 digits": More specifically, the *signed 32-bit integer* range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.